# Java: binary series representation

Tags: java, binary, biginteger

I am doing some experiments on my own about quantization processes etc.

I try to implement a binarization process which makes a "binary string" which will get processed by xor afterwards and some other stuff.

Anyhow the binarization is the following, where d and u are some numbers that will get compared:

```
String b = "";
for (int i = 0; i < u.length; u++) {
    if(d[i] < u[i]) {
        b[i] += '0';
    } else {
        b[i] += '1';
    }
}
```

Currently like described I have a string where each character is 0 or 1.

Using a `BigInteger` gives me an Object where I can XOR two values against each other:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(b, 2);
(...)
BigInteger result = bi.xor(other_bi);
```

Is there another way to achieve what I want to do? I didn't find anything but maybe there is one I have not found?

Comment: Would anyone of the guys putting this on hold rather leave a comment than just flag questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class is more appropriate for representing a sequence of bits. To set a bit you would use the [`BitSet.set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int%29) method.

Comment: +1 BitSet is significantly faster than using BitInteger. Also the API is more natural for this sort of thing.

Comment: One big reason to use java se 7 :) This looks very nice thank you!

Comment: `BitSet` has been around since Java 1.0, @Stefan.

Comment: @Joni: Shame on me, thank you anyway! Really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Taking your example as a BitSet.

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(u.length);
for (int i = 0; i < u.length; u++) 
    if(d[i] >= u[i]) 
       bs.set(i);

BitSet bs2 = ...
bs2.xor(bs); // changes and reuses bs2.
int bitsSet = bs2.cardinality();
int firstSetBit = bs2.nextSetBit(0);
```